# Best way to monitor number of views on a blog post in Django

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am working on a blog webapp and I would like to monitor the number of views a post has. I have decided to use the post detail view to count. And to keep the counter from incrementing for a particular user, I am going to allow only logged users to count and a user can count only once.

this is my post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewers = models.TextField(default="", null=True, blank=True)
    numViews = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I am basically using a field 'viewers' to track users already counted and 'numviews' as the counter.

My views.py function

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # increment post views whenever request is made
        postObject = self.get_object()
        user = request.user

        if postObject.viewers == None:
            postObject.viewers = ""
            postObject.save()

        if user.is_authenticated and user.username not in postObject.viewers:
            # increment 
            postObject.numViews += 1
            postObject.save()
            # add username to viewers list
            postObject.viewers+=user.username
            postObject.save()
            
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the views function, I am checking if the username is already appended to the viewers string, else append it and increment the counter.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this? In the case the blog gets thousands of views, it is going to be a very long string of usernames.

Comment: Which `variable` you pass to acces the `post views` ? `queryset` or `created` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the case the blog gets thousands of views, it is going to be a very long string of usernames.

It will not only be inefficient, but also can result in the wrong result. If you have three users `foo`, `bar` and `foobar`, then if `foo` visits the page, and `bar` visits the page, then if `foobar` visits the page, their view will not be taken into account.

An other problem is that there can be *race conditions* here: if two users visit the same post approximately at the same time, it is possible that the database ends up only updating the object for *one* user, and thus it is like the other user never visited the page.

Normally you determine who has viewed the post through a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='viewed_posts'
        editable=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Then we can implement the view as:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(
        num_views=Count('viewers')
    )

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            __, created = Post.viewers.through.objects.get_or_create(
                post=self.object,
                user=self.request.user
            )
            if created:
                self.object.num_views += 1
        return super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: No need to use get_or_create according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) _"Adding a second time is OK, it will not duplicate the relation:"_. You can simply add without thinking.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, but we need to know if we should increment the `num_views` :) That is the only reason to include it

Comment: You are right, didn't think about that. :)

Comment: Can it can be done in `function based views` ?

Comment: @Progam: yes, simply add the logic in the function where `self.object` is thus the object you fetch. But as wit a lot of reusable logic, class-based views are often better to mix in logic.

Comment: You mean, i should use `request.object` instead of `self.object` ?

Comment: @Progam: no, `object` is the item you want to display, so this is something like `object = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=some_pk)`. The logic to obtain the item is encapsulated in the `DetailView`.

Comment: I already did that in `function based view of detail_view` ( get_object_or_404). So can i access the `ManyToMany` post view in template ?

Comment: @Progam: yes, `object.viewers.all()` will give you the queryset of all the viewers.

Comment: I modified my code with @Willem Van Onsem and it seems to be working correctly. only corection made was self.user -> self.request.user in the post detail view . Also the number of viewers can be access ina post object in html template by ((post.viewers.count}} and in the detail view template as {{object.num_views}}

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code with @Willem Van Onsem and it seems to be working correctly. only corection made was self.user -> self.request.user in the post detail view . Also the number of viewers can be access ina post object in html template by ((post.viewers.count}} and in the detail view template as {{object.num_views}}

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more concise way of counting views would be to use the .Count method. This would allow the count to take place in the database and not in memory.

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post(models.Model):
# ...
viewers = models.ManyToManyField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    related_name='viewed_posts'
    editable=False
)

@property
def num_views(self):
    return self.views.count()
```

and then when adding the user to the views use.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
   post.viewers.add(request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get and update view count in blog Api using post method.
This is very best and Simple

```
this is my model.py code

    class Blog(BaseModel,SlugModel,SeoModel):
        author = 
       models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True)
        author_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=blog_image_directory)
        views_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

This is my views.py code 

from django.db.models import F

class BlogCountViewset(APIView):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        slug=kwargs.get('slug')
        blog=Blog.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        if blog.exists():
            blog.update(views_count=F('views_count')+1)
            return Response({"views_count":blog.last().views_count},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({"message":"blog does not exists"},status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

This is my url code

```
path("blog-view-count/<slug>",
         BlogCountViewset.as_view(),
         name="blog-view-count"),
```

This is only required code